# error using wxWidgets libraries for arm cross-compilation using codelite in linux

Tags: wxwidgets, cross-compiling, codelite

I have added the cross compiler arm-linux-gnueabi into codelite and successfully cross-compiled a sample C program.

Now I'm trying to cross-compile a wxwidget sample program.

Initially it was throwing me errors in setup.h.

I created a link for /usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8/wx/setup.h with /usr/include/wx/setup.h. Now its giving me around 159 errors. I give you some of them for your reference.

```
 /usr/include/wx/defs.h:42:13: error: #error "No Target! You should use wx-config program for compilation flags!"
In file included from /usr/include/wx/cursor.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/wx/event.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/wx/wx.h:25,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/wx/gtk/cursor.h:40:5: error: ‘GdkCursor’ does not name a type
In file included from /usr/include/wx/app.h:570:0,
                 from /usr/include/wx/wx.h:26,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/wx/gtk/app.h:55:5: error: ‘guint’ does not name a type
/usr/include/wx/gtk/app.h:65:5: error: ‘GdkVisual’ does not name a type
```

When I add `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` to my build command it gives me in compatible library errors..

These are the erros I'm stuck on with..

/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu_net-2.8
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu-2.8
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I think I'm doing something wrong in linking libraries for cross compiler. Can anyone help me on this.. I would appreciate any help..

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you have posted the errors you have fixed.  You should post the errors that have you stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I have edited my question with the errors I'm stuck on with.. Hope it would get me some help..

Comment: Does  wx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8  etc exist anywhere?

Comment: I can see a folder named richtext in the path /usr/include/wx/

Comment: That will contain the .h files.  The linker is looking for the built libraries.  Have you built the libraries?

Comment: no I haven't.. How can I do it.. Please forgive my ignorance.. I'm new to this stuffs..

Comment: The codelite docs should explain how to build the wxWidgets libraries. ( I don't use codelite, but MSVS )  The cross-compilation may be making this a bit complicated.  I suggest you edit your question to make it clearer: you want to build the wxWidgets libraries for cross-compilation using codelite.

Comment: How can I build wxwidgets libraries ??? Is it should be done using ./configure ??

Comment: I'm stuck.. Any help would be most appreciated..

Comment: Try following on of the guides to compiling wxWidgets on the wxWiki: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Guides_%26_Tutorials You will need to make some changes for cross compiling however.

Comment: I can only give general advice.  You need to build the libraries using the same compiler (  arm-linux-gnueabi I assume ) and the same settings as when you compile your application.  Then you need to tell your compiler where the new libraries are placed when building your application.  Like all config mgmt problems, simple in concept but hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't cross-compile wxWidgets itself. Or didn't install it if you did.

The thing to keep in mind is that you absolutely shouldn't need to manually create any links. In particular, the one you already made for `wx/setup.h` will almost certainly **break** your other builds, don't do this. Just use the correct `wx-config` for the cross-build.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I haven't cross compiled wxWidgets. I downloaded wxWidgets-2.8.12 and configured it with X11 and without gtk. Now its giving me errors ./src/unix/fontenum.cpp:125:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [coredll_unix_fontenum.o] Error 1

Comment: I'm having a real hard time with these wxWidgets libraries.. Hope you pioneers would help me to get over it..

Comment: I compiled wxwidgets with the following configure options and its giving me the following error..

Comment: configure --x-includes=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include --x-libraries=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux-gnu --with-x11 --without-gtk --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-no_rtti --enable-no_exceptions --disable-threads --disable-sockets --disable-joystick --disable-mdi --disable-printarch --disable-postscript --disable-resources --disable-prologio --with-zlib=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: You probably need to open another question about this to avoid mixing everything together but if you get an error about missing X11 headers your build environment is obviously not set up correctly. You need to ensure that your cross-compiler finds the headers and the libraries correctly...

Comment: I cross compiled my wxwidget library with arm-linux Toolchain.. On compiling a simple widget program its giving me linking errors.. I opened a separate question on this as you suggested.. Please do give your valuable suggestions on that question.. I would appreciate any help..